# {Extending templates in django} In my base.html django put all the content of my head tag into my body tag automatically

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm getting problem with django templates.

my problem come because when I display my website in my browser django put all the content of my head tag into my body tag.

This is my base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SecureKids {% block title %}{{title}}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">{% block apartado %} {% endblock %}</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
             <p class="text-success">{% block msg %}{% endblock %}</p>              
            <div class="row">
                    {% block contenido %}---{% endblock %}

            </div><!-- /.row -->


        </div><!-- /#page-wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

and here's a template that extends from base.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%load i18n%}
{% block apartado %}
{% trans 'Control Panel' %} <small>{% trans 'Device' %} {{device.name}}</small>
{% endblock %}
{% block contenido %}
<h2>{% trans 'WELLCOME' %}</h2>
<div>
<h3>{% trans 'Child:' %} <small>{{device.child.name}}</small></h3>
<h3>{% trans 'Father's device:' %} <small>{{device.name}}</small></h3>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the result in my browser

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
"


"
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SecureKids </title>


    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">
                    Control Panel <small>Device</small>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
             <p class="text-success"></p>               
            <div class="row">

                 <h2>WELLCOME</h2>
                 <div>
                   <h3>Child: <small>m</small></h3>
                   <h3>Father's device: <small>m disp</small></h3>

                </div>      
       </div><!-- /.row -->     
   </div><!-- /#page-wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

function in views.py for this example

```
@login_required
def panel(request,oid):


    device = get_object_or_404(Device,pk=oid,child__father=request.user.id)

    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,"Este dispositivo no existe")
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


    request.session["device"] = device.id
    request.session["devicen"] = device.name
    request.session["childn"] = device.child.name 
    return render_to_response('children/panel.html',{'device':device},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

As you can see in my browser all the content is into body tag, and django also include 3 empty lines just after body tag

I hope somebody can help me
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your relevant **views.py**?

Comment: I just add views.py, but this is a simple example from project, it happen in each template who extend from base.html

Comment: Do the blank lines have the quotes like in the example code you showed? Also, what happens if you remove the `title` block?

Comment: the quotes don't appear in my website but when I inspect it to see the html code the quotes are there, I think this is to mark the three lines. I've tried to remove the title block but the problem continue.., and the most strange is that it only happen with the extending templates

Comment: @user3637447 , I see a missing escape char here `{% trans 'Father's device:' %}` but not sure if is related. So fix it then test again.